# changing the background of a button automatically on a regular interval in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create an animated button by changing its background color on a regular interval automatically. I used following Javascript:

```
var colors = new Array("Red", "GreenYellow", "Fuchsia", "OrangeRed", "Yellow", "Blue", "Navy", "MediumSpringGreen", "Lime", "SteelBlue");
function bcAnimation(y){
    var x;
    x=y;
    x.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*10)];
    setTimeout(bcAnimation(x), 2000);   
}
```

the nested call is not working. the button is changed once. I called the function from the body tag:

```
<body onload='bcAnimation(document.getElementById("x"));'>
```

I also tried it with button onclick event. What I am missing?

Comment: Did any of the answers help you and answer your question? If no, let us know so we can help more. If so, please mark the most helpful answer as "accepted". Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is solved.

Comment: Thank you! You can accept an answer by clicking the checkmark under the vote count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
setTimeout(function(){ bcAnimation(x); }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simplify the whole thing to:

```js
var colors = new Array("Red", "GreenYellow", "Fuchsia", "OrangeRed", "Yellow", "Blue", "Navy", "MediumSpringGreen", "Lime", "SteelBlue");
setInterval(function () {
    x.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 10)];
}, 2000)
```

```html
<button id="x">button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    var curColor = 0;
    var colors = new Array("Red", "GreenYellow", "Fuchsia", "OrangeRed", "Yellow", "Blue", "Navy", "MediumSpringGreen", "Lime", "SteelBlue");
    setInterval(function() {
        $('button.colors').css('background-color', colors[curColor]);
        curColor += 1;
        if (curColor >= colors.length) {
            curColor = 0;
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

```css
button.colors {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="colors"> :D </button>
```